# Matlab array of a single pair

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab function that requires an array of pairs.
It works fine using meshgrid to generate such array.
The problem comes when I call the function with an array of a single pair, the matlab interpreter considers it as an array of 2 elements instead of an array of arrays.

I'll explain with an example:

```
[p,q] = meshgrid(vec1, vec2);
pairs = [p(:) q(:)];
```

now ''pairs'' is an array of couples, but if vec1 and vec2 have only 1 element ''pairs'' is just an array of two elements.

can you help me to generate an array of a single pair?

something like this:

```
aPair =[[a, b]];
aPair(1)
ans =
    [a,b]
```

thank you very much

Comment: In the multi-element case, `pairs` is not an array of arrays; it's a two-column array, just like in the one-element case. Only the number of rows changes. So I don't see your point. In both cases, `pairs(m,n)` accesses the n-th element of the m-th pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a cell array.

You can construct it

```
pairs = arrayfun(@(x,y)[x,y],p(:),q(:),'uni',false);
```

or

```
pairArray = [p(:),q(:)];
pairs = mat2cell(pairArray ,ones(size(pairArray,1),1),2);
```

You access pair #1 as

```
aPair{1}
```

However, instead of going the cell array rout, why not access the rows of `pairArray`?

```
aPair = pairArray(n,:)
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas, "aPair = pairArray(n,:)" is far better. However I still have the problem of the lone pair.